# Drawing arrow in VBA out of range

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to draw an error as part of a larger macro within VBA and hit an error when I try to run the macro on a sheet with 70000+ lines. The code runs without errors on smaller files, so I suspect this is the issue.

Here is an example of the code that doesn't run;

```
xStart = 1661.625
yStart = 76.5
yEnd = 11126311
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddConnector(msoConnectorStraight, xStart, yStart, xStart, yEnd).Select
With Selection.ShapeRange.Line
    .EndArrowheadStyle = msoArrowheadTriangle
    .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
End With
```

Note that if I take off the last one in `yEnd` to make it `1112631`, the arrow draws without an error.

Is there a limit to the length of an arrow object when you are drawing on a sheet? Does anyone have a work around for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The maximum height that you can go up to is `2348 inches` as shown in the image below.

[image]

`2348 inches` is `169056` points. You can check this in Excel by typing `?Application.InchesToPoints(2348)` in Immediate window. However the maximum points that you can go up to is `169156`

You can try this code

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddConnector(msoConnectorStraight, 100, 100, 100, 169156)
```

If you right click on the shape that is added, you will see the size is `2348` inches as shown in the screenshot above. At `169157`, it will throw an error. So to answer your question, `Is there a limit to the length of an arrow object...`, the answer is `169156`.

**Bruteforcing Code** to find the limit.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim shp As Shape
    Dim i As Long

    '~~> I started with 50000 instead of 169000
    '~~> The lower you go the more time it will take obviously
    For i = 169000 To 169158
        On Error Resume Next
        Set shp = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddConnector(msoConnectorStraight, 100, 100, 100, i)
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            Debug.Print "Error at " & i
            Exit For
        Else
           shp.Delete
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Nice, fun fact; when I try to manually pull the shape further, it works but the length in properties stay the same :S

Comment: Yes and if you check the height through drawing tools when you manually increase the height, the height goes up to `2348.52"` after that it remains constant

Comment: Thanks for the response, I figured there was an upper limit but couldn't find the related documentation. Much appreciated!